# Recovering from fork bomb by having a kernel patch allowing to run only recovery process

Tags: linux, kernel, fork

WAS: Reading another question on SO that was migrated to SU : https://superuser.com/questions/435690/does-linux-have-any-measures-to-protect-against-fork-bombs, i was thinking of a solution at kernel level.
I read one proposal at LWN ( http://lwn.net/Articles/435917/ ) but this proposal focuse on fork bomb detection to be able to prevent it.

I would focus on recovery, since detection basically means that system is not usable; what will soon be detected by any user of the system.

I broaden the context to  non fork bomb only : what if your system is unresponsive and you can't get a decent console to it but still don't want to reboot it even cleanly.

So THE QUESTION :

Is it possible to tell kernel by some SysReq command to enter in a recover shell that will run only one process ( and refuse to fork it ) with intent to kill faulty processes; has this feature been ever implemented ? If no, then why ?

Remark i am not speaking of SysReq+i that send SIGKILL to all process, but something that behaves like a SIGSTOP to all processes, it can be another kernel kexec alongside the first allowing to inspect and resume it.

Comment: I one answer but it is not my question. And please comment the -1 when you put one.

Comment: You should not recover from fork bombs. You should avoid them happening.

Comment: that's exactly where we disagree. There are other case when you system is too busy to process anything where you would really want to interrupt it and inspect its current misbahviour. I state such feature won't be useless. Of course it does not replace protection, but you should always have multiple defence lines and recovery actions.

Comment: The original Unix philosophy was that root behave cleverly and is given all the rights (including to burn the system) and their responsibilities. It has not "multiple defence lines" (only one: root vs non-root). Today's Linux systems have also `capabilities(7)`.

Comment: Then the so powerfull root who has ALL rights has not the right to stop all processes else his own ???...

Comment: `root` can `kill -KILL` every process (except perhaps `/sbin/init` of pid 1), even those owned by others. I routinely do that when sysadmining (but I first start by `kill -TERM`-ing them). And `root` could use `killall` or `pkill` or `pgrep`

Comment: If system is overloaded and you still want to not reboot system and just detect where the fork bomb comes from ( because of security rules ) and not want to kill any processes ( because it will cost you to loose customers satisfcation ) . How do you do currently ?

Comment: You saw the other question was moved to SU and you still create a question here?? Why? Why do you add more work to people who try to keep this place clean? Please, read FAQ before posting next time.

Comment: @whalther my goal is not to add any additionnal burden, and i think it definitely is a SO question since i expected kernel coders to answer. I should not have let the initial context that triggered in my mind this question, it was fork bomb but could just have been really wider (system overload). I will do some coding around that and come back with code, meanwhile i will delete this question that triggered your comment.

Answer (score 2):

You can always limit, for a non-root user, the maximal number of processes with [setrlimit(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setrlimit.2.html) syscall with `RLIMIT_NPROC`.

You could use the bash `ulimit` builtin (or `limit` if using `zsh` as your shell). You can also  `/etc/security/limits.conf` and/or `/etc/pam.d/` to limit it "system-wide" (but tuning the limit user by user if so wanted, etc.). [PAM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_PAM) is very powerful for that.

I don't think you need some risky kernel patch. You just want to administer your machine with care.

And you don't care about `root` fork bombs: if a malicious (or stupid) user gets root access, your Linux system is doomed anyway (even without root fork bombs). Nobody care about them because by definition root is trusted and needs to behave carefully & cleverly. (likewise, root can `/bin/rm -rf /` but that is usually stupid, as stupid as a root fork bomb, hence no protections exist against both mistakes...)

And a kernel patch would be difficult : you want the root to be able to run several processes (at least, the recovery shell and the child command, possibly piped), not only one. !Kernel patches can be brittle and then crash the entire system....

Of course you are free to patch your kernel, since it is [free software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software). However, making an *interesting* patch and getting the kernel community attracted by it is also a social issue (and a much harder thing to achieve). Good luck. [LKLM](https://lkml.org/) is a better place to discuss that.

PS.Sending `SIGSTOP` to every non *init* process won't help much w.r.t. a root fork bomb: you won't be able to type any shell command, because your shell would also and always be stopped!

PPS. The LWN article quoted in the question had comments mentionning `cgroup`-s which could be relevant.

Comment: you didn't answer my question anyway. What if as root i launch a fork bomb by mistake. The question is about how to recover form it, not how to protect from it.

Comment: ok for the fork bomb context, what if my question didn't mention fork bomb but just : unavaible attacked system under too heavy load for maintenance ?

Comment: SIGSTOP might not be so useful but we currently run a secondary kernel that dumps first kernel content for forensics, what if secondary kernel just take over the first let it in pending state but allows to operate on it ?

Comment: Feel free to patch your kernel as you want, this is the freedom of free software. That does not mean that your system will be more robust as a whole (very probably, using some hypervisor would be more robust), and that does not mean that the kernel community will accept your patches.

Comment: Will such feature be useful ?

Comment: You have to implement it first, to publish your patch as a free software (under GPLv2+ license), to convince others to use it, and maybe to propose it to the kernel community. I wish you the best luck, it is a long journey (probably more than one year, not a few days). I am not convinced it is useful, but I am not a kernel expert. I suggest first to become extremely familiar with sysadministration, http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com; and kernel code.

Comment: Thanks i will anyway continue to sharpen my linux knowledge, even if i am not be a newbie on that subject ( please don't stop to my nick ).

Comment: After reviewing a quite recent kernel archive discussion, getting access to a unique process by pressing a SysReq key was proposed, and a patch was submitted that has not yet emerged. Not sure even if it will. I let this topic in this state, i am of course not so happy to have negatives evaluation, but that should not prevent me to continue using SO.